# ui форма verticalSpacer не отрабатывает, что делать?

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Создал проект "приложение qt widgets".Накидал три элемента на форму в Qt дизайнере, кнопке строго задал максимальный размер, соединил сплитерами, растянул грид лейаутом. И вот результат, сильно удивился :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделайте clean and make, и попробуйте снова

Comment: @gil9red может быть это монитор у меня новый, но я запустил драйвера  и перезагрузил его

Comment: Тыкните правой кнопкой на проект и там должна быть подобная команда (или qmake)

Comment: @gil9red извините забыл самое главное, попробовал и очищал и запускал только кумейк, не сработало.

Comment: При изменении окна кнопка движется за правой границей? Посмотрите в папке проекта или на уровень выше папку с названием вашего проекта, там еще будет добавлено DEBUG или RELEASE с версией Qt, так вот в той папке будет храниться сгенерированный mainwindow_ui.cpp, удалите его и снова соберите проект

Comment: Прикрепите к вопросу код из `ui_mainwindow.h`

Comment: тьфу, mainwindow_ui.h

Comment: @gil9red, `ui_mainwindow.h`)